# MySQL query to find if a value of one column in one table is between two values in two columns on another table

Tags: mysql

Long title question, so my apologies for that! I have two tables, one is as follows:

```
Student Name         Grade
John Doe             96
John Foe             65
Dan Doe              76
Mary Doe             85
```

The other table, is as follows:

```
Grade Start      Grade End       Status
0                60              Bad Student
61               70              OK Student
71               80              Good Student
81               90              Great Student
91               100             Honor Student
```

I am trying to create a MySQL view that will pull the student's grade, and tell me the status of that student such as:

```
Student Name     Grade      Status
John Doe         90         Honor Student
John Foe         65         OK Student
```

So on and so forth. I can't think of a query that will give me that information. I'm at a complete loss with the query, any help?

```
SELECT student_name, student_grade from student_grade_table WHERE ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```
SELECT s.student_name, s.grade, g.status
FROM students AS s
JOIN grades as g ON s.grade BETWEEN g.grade_start AND g.grade_end
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00b9a/1)